# Qt, How to add icons to tabWidget titles?

Tags: linux, qt, tabwidget

I have a tabWidget in my application and I want to add icons near the titles.
how can I do it?

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`int QTabWidget::addTab ( QWidget * page, const QIcon & icon, const QString & label )`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtabwidget.html#addTab-2) function. The second parameter allows to specify an QIcon for the tab. See also [`void QTabBar::setTabIcon ( int index, const QIcon & icon )`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtabbar.html#setTabIcon).